# Table exists, but I'm receiving "Invalid object name" error when calling API

Tags: c#, sql, .net, umbraco

I'm building an API using c#/.NET

I've created a table and can run queries on the it using SQL Server and Server Explorer in Visual Studio. However when I call my API I receive the error "Invalid object name 'dbo.TableName'."

My API controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<TableName> Get()
{
    var db = DatabaseContext.Database;
    var response = db.Query<TableName>("SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName").ToList();
    return response;
}
```

and in my Database.cs file:

```
[TableName("dbo.TableName")]
[PrimaryKey("Id")]
[ExplicitColumns]
public partial class TableName : MyDB.Record<TableName>  
{
    [Column] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column] public string SomeColumn { get; set; }
    [Column] public string AnotherColumn { get; set; }
}
```

The above method is identical to other GET methods for my other tables. I've looked into any potential pluralization issues, and as far as I can tell, that doesn't pertain to my situation. I'm new to C#/.NET.

Comment: Either the table name is misspelled or you are connected to the wrong database/server.

Comment: Also, double check the schema (dbo), just in case the table belongs to a different one.

Comment: That was it. I was connected to the wrong database. Not sure how I could have let that get by me. Shucks. Thanks guys!

Comment: edit: Sorry... re-reading the comments .. @GordonLinoff should be the one posting an answer so the question can be closed! :)